# Why is xpath not scraping certain html (html that appears all green and is at the end of the page)?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am a beginner and I am trying to scrape hockey statistics of players on hockey-reference.com. 
An example of a player page I am scraping from is https://www.hockey-reference.com/players/a/abdelju01.html.

At the very bottom of this page is html that appears in all green, and xpath won't scrape any of it.

Specifically, I need the text contained in the fourth tbody tag, because I want to scrape Corsi and Fenwick scores. However, that tbody tag html is in green, and this xpath code:

```
list = player.xpath("//tbody[3]//tr//text()")
```

returns an empty list.

This code: `player.xpath("//tbody[1]//tr//text()")` returns exactly what I need from the second tbody tag, which is html that appears in the normal color coded fashion.

What is up with this green html? Is it blocked somehow? Is there any way I can scrape it?

Comment: Hi. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and especially [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have an examples for you, how to find values via xpath.
These are for Corsi:

```
'//tr[1][not(@class="bold")]/td[@data-stat="corsi_for"]'
'//tr[1][not(@class="bold")]/td[@data-stat="corsi_against"]'
'//tr[1][not(@class="bold")]/td[@data-stat="corsi_pct"]'
'//tr[1][not(@class="bold")]/td[@data-stat="corsi_rel_pct"]'
```

You can change the row from the first `//tr[1]` to the second simply changing: `//tr[2]`

Hope, this will help you.